# MongoDB StagePipelineDefinition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my MongoDB StagePipelineDefinition

```
[
    { "$set" : { "sources.0.serialNumber" : { "$ifNull" : ["$sources.0.serialNumber", "87X321910212"] } } }
    { "$set" : { "sources.0.serialNumber" : { "$cond" : { "if" : { "$lt" : ["$lastTimestamp.ticks", NumberLong("637816639450000000")] }, "then" : "87X321910212", "else" : "$sources.0.serialNumber" } } } }
]
```

The result I got is not what I expected.The serialNumber should be a property of the first object of the sources array. I couldn't figure out where my definition goes wrong.

[image]

Comment: `"sources.0.serialNumber"` - this syntax of using the array index (`0`) may not be valid in an aggregation `$set` (or `$addFields`) stage. That syntax is used with MongoDB Query Language queries. You need to use Aggregation Expression Operators, e.g., `$arrayElemAt`.

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: In an aggregation pipeline you cannot access array elements by `"$sources.0.serialNumber"`, Use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/), e.g. `{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$sources.serialNumber", 0 ] }` or [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/)

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and expected output.